# Merge two rows into one with different text arrangement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to merge two row into one, but with specific arrangement only with SQL

My first row is with geo data in this format

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>23.704822,43.139239,0.0 23.704758,43.139544,0.0 23.705024,43.139568,0.0 23.705735,43.1397,0.0 23.706165,43.139754,0.0 23.706769,43.139848,0.0 23.707195,43.13988,0.0 23.70759,43.139877,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
```

And the second row

```
<Point><coordinates>23.724567,43.136242,0.0</coordinates></Point>
```

The question is how to merge those two rows into one with format like this only with MySQL >>>

```
    <geometry>
<polygon>23.732246,43.132842,0.0 23.732455,43.132991,0.0 23.732673,43.133136,0.0 23.733004,43.133328,0.0 23.733394,43.133522,0.0 23.733649,43.133625,0.0</polygon>
<point>23.724567,43.136242,0.0</point>
</geometry>
```

I'm using Workbench 6.3

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
SELECT 
    concat( '<geometry>',group_concat( col_name SEPARATOR '' ) ,'</geometry>' )
```

feel free to use any group by to adjust too :)
i think it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @polygonXml = '<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>23.704822,43.139239,0.0 23.704758,43.139544,0.0 23.705024,43.139568,0.0 23.705735,43.1397,0.0 23.706165,43.139754,0.0 23.706769,43.139848,0.0 23.707195,43.13988,0.0 23.70759,43.139877,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>';
set @pointXml = '<Point><coordinates>23.724567,43.136242,0.0</coordinates></Point>';

set @poligon = ExtractValue(@polygonXml, '/Polygon/outerBoundaryIs/LinearRing/coordinates');
set @point = ExtractValue(@pointXml, '/Point/coordinates');

SELECT CONCAT('<geometry>', '<polygon>', @poligon, '</polygon>', '<point>', @point, '</point>', '</geometry>');
```

Main theme is that in MySQL 5.1 you have function [ExtractValue](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html). You can manipulate with xml data like you want. In my instance xml data in variables, but also you can extract it from query

Comment: Thank you, but the value of polygons and points is different on each row

How to do that with table on screentshot?

http://imgur.com/a/LOiHc

Comment: @Stanislav, Could you explain how determine which 'Polygon' should be contacted with 'Point'? Is it first 'polygon' with next 'point' or several 'polygons' with several 'points'?

Comment: As you see on the uploaded screenshot on previous comment the polygons do not have "id" and points have "id"